# Using MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Am using MultiFieldQueryParser for parsing strings like a.a., b.b., etc
But after parsing, its removing the dots in the string.
What am i missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you give more info about what you're trying to do, I can help you further.

Comment: am working on a book search api using Lucene.User can search for a book whose title or description field contains C.F.A...is this info sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the MultiFieldQueryParser does what you think it does.  Also...I'm not sure I know what you're trying to do.

I do know that with any query parser, strings like 'a.a.' and 'b.b.' will have the periods stripped out because, at least with the default Analyzer, all punctuation is treated as white space.

As far as the MultiFieldQueryParser goes, that's just a QueryParser that allows you to specify multiple default fields to search. So with the query

> title:"Of Mice and Men" "John Steinbeck"

The string "John Steinbeck" will be looked for in all of your default fields whereas "Of Mice and Men" will only be searched for in the title field.

Answer (score 1):

What analyzer is your parser using?  If it's StopAnalyzer then the dot could be a stop word and is thus ignored.  Same thing if it's StandardAnalyzer which cleans up input (includes removing dots).

Comment: thanks for ur inputs...am using StandardAnalyzer alongwith a list of stop words...my list of stop words does not have "." in it.

Answer (score 1):

(Repeating my answer from [the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660298/multifieldqueryparser-is-removing-dots-from-the-acronym). One of these should be deleted).

The `StandardAnalyzer` specifically handles acronyms, and converts C.F.A. (for example) to cfa. This means you should be able to do the search, as long as you make sure you use the same analyzer for the indexing and for the query parsing.

I would suggest you run some more basic test cases to eliminate other factors. Try to user an ordinary `QueryParser` instead of a multi-field one.

Here's some code I wrote to play with the `StandardAnalyzer`:

```
StringReader testReader = new StringReader("C.F.A. C.F.A word");
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("title", testReader);
System.out.println(tokenStream.next());
System.out.println(tokenStream.next());
System.out.println(tokenStream.next());
```

The output for this, by the way was:

```
(cfa,0,6,type=<ACRONYM>)
(c.f.a,7,12,type=<HOST>)
(word,13,17,type=<ALPHANUM>)
```

Note, for example, that if the acronym doesn't end with a dot then the analyzer assumes it's an internet host name, so searching for "C.F.A" will not match "C.F.A." in the text.