# Lucene analyzer and dots

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Am newbie to Lucene.

Is there any way I can make Lucene analyzer not ignore dots in the string??
for example,if my search criteria is: "A.B.C.D",Lucene should give me only those documents in the search results which have "A.B.C.D" and not "ABCD"....

Answer (score 5):

It's all about the analyzer you use. The [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) does [some complicated things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660298/multifieldqueryparser-is-removing-dots-from-the-acronym/661316#661316) with dotted names, in an attempt to "Do What You Mean". Perhaps the [`WhitespaceAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html) will be a better match for your needs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, new WhitespaceAnalyzer(), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("text", "A.B.C.D DEF", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    iw.addDocument(doc);
    iw.close();

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("text", new WhitespaceAnalyzer());

    // prints 0 
    System.out.println(searcher.search(queryParser.parse("ABCD"), 1).totalHits);

    // prints 1
    System.out.println(searcher.search(queryParser.parse("A.B.C.D"), 1).totalHits);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks...using whitespaceanalyzer,how do i feed in stop words to lucene?

Comment: Basically, you have to write a new analyzer, which is not that hard. If you want more details, I suggest you open a new question.